# how to publish a printer in 14.04

Tags: printing

In ubuntu 14.04 My Printer is showing as shared but not published. I don't have a server settings button to publish my printer where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings->Printers, then move your mouse pointer over the bar at the top of the screen to make the menu appear and select Server->Settings.  Select Publish Shared Printers ..., Allow printing from internet and Allow users to cancel any job ...